# GetStream Activity component not rendering new lines properly

Tags: reactjs, getstream-io

The stream activity component
https://getstream.github.io/react-activity-feed/#activity is not able to render new lines.

```
 {
  "actor": {
  },
  "attachments": {
    "files": [],
    "images": []
  },
  "foreign_id": "",
  "id": "",
  "latest_reactions": {},
  "latest_reactions_extra": {},
  "object": "Post\npost\npost\npost",
  "origin": null,
  "own_reactions": {},
  "reaction_counts": {},
  "target": "",
  "text": "Post\npost\npost\npost",
  "time": "2019-06-12T19:11:46.728935",
  "verb": "post"
}
```

In the above data the text contains new lines "Post\npost\npost\npost" still it is coming in a single line as in the image below.

[image: Single line text]

Is there any way this can be handled in the component.

Comment: I think it's because how the component wraps the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by setting the following css:

```
.raf-activity__content p {
    white-space: pre-line
}
```

I have also included this in the latest version(`0.9.16`) of `react-activity-feed` so you won't have to do it yourself.